# Downsizing of images with javascript or jsp

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I'm building a website like flickr or 500px, i have a page full of photos, i have resized them with css properties but the images are still at full resolution and the loading time of the page takes something like 2 minutes and even when it's loaded it won't scroll. I need some kind of script (that i wasn't able to find) wich reduces the acutual dimesion in MB to something much much lower e.g. from 3000x4000 to 300x400

Comment: It's not clear whether you want a client or server side solution.

Comment: It must be server side solution. if he does on client side then it will be meaningless. @OP I suggest you to mention the server language you are using as tag.

Comment: i'm using jsp at the moment

Comment: Please refer this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277571/is-there-a-cdn-which-provides-on-demand-image-resizing-cropping-sharpening-et.

Comment: You can create thumbnail versions of the photos using the BufferedImage class and have your page load them instead of the full size originals. I can be more specific if you want.

Comment: Yes Please thank you

Answer (score 1):

It happens that I've just handled the same concern a few days ago.

The key is the `<canvas>` element and its `drawImage` method.

Below is the function I wrote. It scales the input image to a target width, but it should be easy to adapt to take as parameter a maximum width or height, or a ratio, or whatever.

```
var scaleToWidth = function (img, targetWidth) {
    /* take in an HTMLImageElement (<img>)
     ouput a HTMLCanvasElement (<canvas>)    */

    var w = img.naturalWidth;
    var h = img.naturalHeight;

    var targetHeight = targetWidth * (h / w);

    var interimCanvas    = document.createElement('canvas');
    interimCanvas.width  = w;
    interimCanvas.height = h;
    var interimCtx       = interimCanvas.getContext('2d');
    var redrawnCanvas, redrawnCtx;
    var i                = 2;
    var newWidth, newHeight;

    redrawnCanvas        = document.createElement('canvas');
    redrawnCanvas.width  = targetWidth;
    redrawnCanvas.height = targetHeight;
    redrawnCtx           = redrawnCanvas.getContext('2d');

    if (w > targetWidth) {

        /* we do multiple passes, each time scaling the image by half.
         For some reason, this gives a smoother result than scaling directly
         to target size.
         We stop when halving once more would bring us below the target size.
         */

        interimCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        do {
            redrawnCanvas                    = document.createElement('canvas');
            newWidth                         = interimCanvas.width / 2;
            newHeight                        = interimCanvas.height / 2;
            redrawnCanvas.width              = newWidth;
            redrawnCanvas.height             = newHeight;
            redrawnCtx                       = redrawnCanvas.getContext('2d');
            redrawnCtx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
            redrawnCtx.drawImage(interimCanvas, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            interimCanvas = redrawnCanvas;
            i++;
        } while (interimCanvas.width / targetWidth > 2);
        //final scalling to target width
        redrawnCanvas        = document.createElement('canvas');
        redrawnCanvas.width  = targetWidth;
        redrawnCanvas.height = targetHeight;
        redrawnCtx           = redrawnCanvas.getContext('2d');
        redrawnCtx.drawImage(interimCanvas, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    } else {
        redrawnCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    }

    return redrawnCanvas;
};
```

Comment: How do i use this, i'm not very familiar with java